# Google RateLimiter not Working for counter

Tags: java, guava, throttling

I have case of limiting calls to 100/s.

I am thinking of using Google Guava RateLimiter. I tested it like this:-

```
int cps = 100;
    RateLimiter limiter = RateLimiter.create(cps);
for(int i=0;i<200;i++) {
   limiter.acquire();
   System.out.print("\rNumber of records processed = " + i+1);
}
```

But the code did not stop at 100 records to let 1 sec be completed. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The RateLimiter is working ok. The problem is that your output is buffered, because you are not flushing it each time. Usually, standard output is line-buffered. So if you had written

```
System.out.println("Number of records processed = " + (i+1));
```

you would have seen a pause at 100. However, what you have:

System.out.print("\rNumber of records processed = " + i+1);

has two problems. First, the "\r" is not taken as a new line and does not cause flushing; therefore the whole output is buffered and is printed to the console all in one go. Second, you need to put (i+1) in parentheses. What you have appends i to the string, and then appends 1 to the resultant string.

Comment: RateLimiter is not meant to have a "hard" time wait on the given qps, it tries it's best to AVERAGE to the given rate. See discussion https://groups.google.com/g/guava-discuss/c/UST-DM5BMAo?pli=1

Answer (score 2):

Besides @DodgyCodeException's suggestions regarding output flushing and concatenating `+1`, let's run this code to make sure you understand how `RateLimiter` works:

```
final double permitsPerSecond = 1;
RateLimiter limiter = RateLimiter.create(permitsPerSecond);
final Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.createStarted();
int i = 0;
for (; i < 2 * permitsPerSecond; i++) {
  limiter.acquire();
}
System.out.println("Elapsed = " + stopwatch.stop().elapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) + "ms");
System.out.println("Number of records processed = " + i);
```

(Note that I set number of tries to twice the `permitsPerSecond` number.) When you set `permitsPerSecond` to `1`, you'll see:

> Elapsed = 1001ms
>   Number of records processed = 2

For `permitsPerSecond = 10;` and `permitsPerSecond = 100;` it'd approaches (in mathematical sense) 2s limit, because 11th or 101st try waits for limit set in `RateLimiter`:

> Elapsed = 1902ms
>   Number of records processed = 20

and

> Elapsed = 1991ms
>   Number of records processed = 200